# compile opengl red book 9 example

Tags: opengl, makefile, compiler-errors, g++

I have taken from github the red book examples.
Under debian jessie I run cmake and all it is ok.
When I run make I get this error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/cstdint:35:0,
             from /home/antonio/Documenti/CG/OGLPG-9th-    Edition/lib/vdds.cpp:16:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file                          requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This    support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
```

. . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line in the CmakeLists.txt file:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -std=gnu++0x")
```

Comment: It should be CMakeLists.txt for Linux at least (case sensitive).